# Error when using breqn and nowidow?

Tags: math-mode, breqn

I've been using the `nowidow` package with the option `all` loaded like so

```
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
```

From the package documentation it says "The all option sets the widow and orphan penalties for the whole document
upon loading the package". I must confess I'm fairly ignorant to how this package works as everything has seemed to work fine in this set-up up until now. However, I just came across this error when trying to use `breqn` and

```
\begin{dmath}
.
.
\end{dmath}
```

I get the following error: `Package breqn Error: eq@repack penalty neq 0,1,2,3. \end{dmath}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
%
\begin{dmath}
(\dot{x}_i, \dot{y}_i) \cdot \mathbf{n}_i \approx \mathrm{i}\omega \left( h\theta_2\sin{(\alpha_i + \beta_i)} + r_i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\sin{(2\alpha_i + \beta_i)} 
- \frac{y_L + y_R}{2} \cos{(\alpha_i + \beta_i)} \right)
\end{dmath}
%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and reported it to the developer [here](https://github.com/raphink/nowidow/issues/5).

Try using:

```
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000
```

instead of `nowidow`.